# Infanticide rate, divided by the sex of the murderer

Tags: data-request, crime

Ideally the data would include a cross-section of countries.

Spinelli (2008) writes on p.xx

"Although infanticide may be viewed as an act of child abuse (Lowenstein
1997), and males are responsible for half of these crimes, child abuse
by fathers is a neglected area of study. Of 66 studies of child abuse published
in the literature over 5 years, 28 included only mothers; 2 included
fathers, and the 36 remaining articles neglected to mention sex differences
(Martin 1984). Haskett et al. (1996) reviewed 126 articles of maltreatment
from 1989 through 1994; males were included in fewer than half
(47.7%) of 77 reviewed articles. Only 3 studies included males, yet 40 involved
female participants."

Spinelli, M. G. (Ed.). (2008). Infanticide: Psychosocial and legal perspectives on mothers who kill. American Psychiatric Pub.